# Cross-referencing with label inside document

Tags: cross-referencing

I have an issue with referencing inside the text, i use the `\label` for every figure I have and Table, but when i state in my text that see `Figure \ref`
instead of giving me Figure 5 (or etc) it gives me Figure 4.1 which represent the section that the table of figure is written in.

```
\documentclass[authoryear,preprint,review,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{adjustbox} 

\usepackage{lineno}

\begin{document}

\begin{flushleft}
\begin{figure}[H]\label{East}
\includegraphics[width=1.3\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{figures/2.pdf}
\caption{mesh }
\end{figure}
\end{flushleft}

The part of the text that tell that you have to see Figure \ref{East}  




\end{document}
```

Is there a way to cross reference my text and have the actual numbers of Figures of tables that i cross reference

Comment: Put the `\label{East}` after `\caption{}` like `\caption{mesh }\label{East}`  or inside like `\caption{mesh\label{East}}`

Comment: @HarishKumar, thank you very much and sorry about the question but i m following instructions from tutorial , trying to learn Latex. thank you again